# How do I add a footer View to a child List in a ExpandableListActivity?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I've been attempting to work out how to add a child `View` to a child `List` in an `ExpandableListActivity`, but to no avail.

I can get the `ExpandableListView` and call `addFooterView()` on it, but that just adds the new `View` to the group list.  (The data comes from a `Cursor`).

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Cheers

James

Comment: Its hard to really tell what's going on without your code, but one caveat with addFooterView() is that you must call that before setAdapter()

Comment: Thanks. I have successfully called addFooterView() (as you point out, after setting the adapter) and it just does what I stated above (added it to the group entries).  I'm not sure having code really helps here.  The question is quite straight forward - how do I do this?

Comment: You need to set it *before* not after.

Comment: Sorry, it was late. I did mean before. The question still stands though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `ExpandableListView.addChildFooterView()` method, or even `ExpandableListView.addFooterView()` for that matter.  The method you are calling is the inherited `ListView.addFooterView()`, which just adds the view as the last item in the entire list.  It was not overridden for group/child behavior.

The simplest way to do this is probably just to build something into your `ExpandableListAdapter` implementation so that `getChildrenCount()` returns the data set size + 1, and then return the footer view in `getChildView()` for the appropriate position.  Also, `getChildView()` provides a boolean parameter to flag when it is retrieving the last child in any specific group.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I discovered that on my travels through the source.  Another option, I believe, would be to implement a wrapper adapter of sorts.

Comment: i tried this approach and when collapsing the first group of childViews, it works but when collapsing the next set of childViews, i get unexpected behavoour of crashes

Answer (score 2):

I had made a custom adapter like this then pass its instance to my ExpandableListView

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
Context context;
List<ParentObject> parentObjects;

public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<ParentObject> parentObjects)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.parentObjects = parentObjects;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentObjects.size();
}

 //Add 2 to childcount. The first row and the last row are used as header and footer to childview
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return parentObjects.get(i).childObjects.size() +2;
}

@Override
public ParentObject getGroup(int i) {
    return parentObjects.get(i);
}

@Override
public ChildObject getChild(int i, int i2) {
    return parentObjects.get(i).childObjects.get(i2);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    ParentObject currentParent = parentObjects.get(i);
    if(view ==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_row,null);
    }
    TextView txtMother = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMother);
    TextView txtFather = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFather);
    txtMother.setText(currentParent.mother);
    txtFather.setText(currentParent.father);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ParentObject currentParent = getGroup(groupPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //the first row is used as header
    if(childPosition ==0)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_header, null);
        TextView txtHeader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        txtHeader.setText(currentParent.textToHeader);
    }

    //Here is the ListView of the ChildView
    if(childPosition>0 && childPosition<getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)
    {
        ChildObject currentChild = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition-1);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row,null);
        TextView txtChildName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtChildName);
        TextView txtChildAge = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtChildAge);
        txtChildName.setText(currentChild.childName);
        txtChildAge.setText("Age: " + String.valueOf(currentChild.age));
    }
    //the last row is used as footer
    if(childPosition == getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_footer,null);
        TextView txtFooter = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFooter);
        txtFooter.setText(currentParent.textToFooter);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Here is solution to the issue http://robusttechhouse.com/how-to-add-header-footer-to-expandablelistview-childview/. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

There is a way more easier solution:

Just set a "OnClickListener" to the applied View:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, null);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //do something
 }
});
```

Very easy thing which solved it!